# AdMob - how to check displayed Ad category?

Tags: admob

I have AdMob integrated with my application and I can see that people are clicking some ads. I would like to know what ad category has better click ratio than others. For instance people are more likely to click on a "clothing" ad than on a "medication" ad. This could help me filter out some Ad categories to generate better click ratio. Is it possible with AdMob panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdMob is actually doing this on your behalf right now. The serving system is smart enough to know what kinds of things your users are particularly likely to be interested in, and picks ads that it thinks will match. There's no need to manually adjust the categories.

I should mention that this isn't unique to AdMob. Every ad network that serves interest-based ads is designed to match a useful ad with an interested user.